# R: Add rows depending on values in the previous value row

Tags: r, database, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a database, let's say it looks like this:

| Date | Company | Gains/Losses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-12-30 | Porsche | 27261 |
| 2019-12-10 | Exxonmobil | 10358890 |
| 2019-12-10 | Apple | 154689 |
| 2019-12-10 | Samsung | 119289 |

And I have many other databases, with the same or maybe fewer companies than the ones appearing here but with other dates, something like this:

| Date | Company | Gains/Losses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-31 | Porsche | 34264 |
| 2018-12-10 | Exxonmobil | 11959790 |
| 2018-12-10 | Apple | 154689 |

And I want to merge those tables so it looks like this:

| Date | Company | Gains/Losses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-12-30 | Porsche | 27261 |
| 2018-12-31 | Porsche | 34264 |
| 2019-12-10 | Exxonmobil | 10358890 |
| 2018-12-10 | Exxonmobil | 11959790 |
| 2019-12-10 | Apple | 154689 |
| 2018-12-10 | Apple | 154689 |
| 2019-12-10 | Samsung | 119289 |

Basically, I want the info of each company to be right after another. As you can see, the columns in the databases are the same. If the company is in one of the tables and not in the other, then it will simply appear once in the final table.

I've tried several times to use 'merge' (changing its conditions) but it never ends up as I want. Do you know what could be used here?

Comment: looks like simple case of `rbind(table1, table2)` and then sort by name, date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to combine two tables with the same columns then arrange by company.

full_table <- bind_rows(data1, data2) %>% arrange(Company)

Comment: While it's obvious to me that this uses `dplyr`, because it wasn't explicitly requested or discussed in the OP, you should mention this in your answer. (And it helps presentation to use [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).)

Answer (score 1):

I would use rbind.

```
df<- rbind(df1, df2)
```